# How do I Read OData URL parameter values in C# action?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, parameters, odata, url-parameters

#### I am trying to read Parameter values in C# which are being passed to odata request

In the below request I am passing $filter and expecting to read filter value

**URL**: `http://localhost:57097/Lead?$filter=AssignedToID eq 21987 and IsDeleted eq false`

I am using this code to read parameter value
`HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("$filter");`

and it is returning as **"AssignedToID eq 21987 and IsDeleted eq false"**

*But I am expecting to read the value of **AssignedToID** i.e. **21987** and **IsDeleted** i.e. **false***

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (see [mcve]). Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and will most likely not be answered. **For more Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Read options from controller action**

```
public IQueryable<_MODELNAME_> Get(ODataQueryOptions<_MODELNAME_> Options)
{

......

}
```

**Step 2: Read BinaryOperatorNode from options**

```
var binaryOperator = Options.Filter.FilterClause.Expression as BinaryOperatorNode;
string filters = getWhereClause(binaryOperator);
```

**Step 3: Create below recursive function to find all filter values**

```
private static string getWhereClause(BinaryOperatorNode node)
{  
    var s = "";
    if (node.Left is SingleValuePropertyAccessNode && node.Right is ConstantNode)
    {
        var property = node.Left as SingleValuePropertyAccessNode ?? node.Right as SingleValuePropertyAccessNode;
        var constant = node.Left as ConstantNode ?? node.Right as ConstantNode;

        if (property != null && property.Property != null && constant != null && constant.Value != null)
        {
            s += $" {property.Property.Name} {getStringValue(node.OperatorKind)} '{constant.Value}' ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (node.Left is BinaryOperatorNode)
            s += getWhereClause(node.Left as BinaryOperatorNode);

        if (node.Right is BinaryOperatorNode)
        {
            s += $" {getStringValue(node.OperatorKind)} ";
            s += getWhereClause(node.Right as BinaryOperatorNode);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```